# PHPMailer timeout o some server

Tags: php, phpmailer

from yesterday I'm desperately trying to run a very simple e-mail script with PHPMailer, latest version.

The most absurd thing is that the same script on two servers does not work, but on another it does.

This is my attempt (from PHPMailer examples):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";

$mail->Password = "xxxxx";

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';

$mail->Body = 'Test';

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Output debug:

```
2017-06-08 08:43:55 Connection: opening to smtp.live.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()

2017-06-08 08:44:58 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.live.com:587 (Connection timed out) [/home/public_html/work/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php line 292]

2017-06-08 08:44:58 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I think it depends on the configuration of the server. Which parameter do I have to look at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $mail->Timeout       =   60; // set the timeout (seconds)  Add this and try

Comment: Do you have a firewall or the restriction of using the port 587 for SMTP communications in the servers where it does not work?

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar no changes
FedericoJoséSorenson honestly, I do not know

Comment: @Andrea  ,.. Please Comment This Line ....  $mail->isSMTP();

Comment: Without that line it works...but this use standard php mail()?

Comment: Have you perhaps considered following the link to the troubleshooting guide given in the error message? It tells you what tests you need to do to diagnose problems like this. It's very likely your ISP is blocking outbound SMTP.

Answer (score 3):

**No Need To Used:**     `$mail->isSMTP();`

> Comment This ...     `$mail->isSMTP();`

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 

$body = file_get_contents('test.html');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

---

```
$mail->Timeout =   60; // set the timeout (seconds)
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // don't close the connection between messages
```

Comment: Turn Off Your Firewall and Then Try It.

Comment: Without $mail->isSMTP(); it works...but this use standard php mail()?

Comment: $mail->isSMTP(); .. its Set mailer to use SMTP.. but its not needed i thinnk

Comment: @Andrea if it's solve your ans, please accept it.